# Regular Expression to avoid optional group inside an URL

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression to validate an URL like this:

- **Valid**

  - http://url-example.com
  - http://url-example.com/anything
  - http://**www**.url-example.com
  - http://**www**.url-example.com/anything
- **Not valid**

  - http://url-example.com**.br** (not valid)
  - http://www.url-example.com**.br** (not valid)
  - http://www.url-example.com**.br/anything** (not valid)

The main goal is to ignore all URLs finishing with .br **or** with .br plus the subdirectories.

In Java I'm doing this:

```
Pattern.compile("http:\\/\\/(www\\.)?url-example.com^(\\.br).*");
```

But it's not working... I believe that's something wrong with the `^(\\.br)`. Is there any way to achieve this kind of validation with regex?

Comment: So basically, you need to check whether there is a \ after `.com` ? or is `http://www.url-example.com.au` *valid*?

Comment: Since you are explicitly handling a URL, you should think about using [`java.net.URL.getPath`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getPath()) to only filter the path and not any other url element like parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a neagtive lookahead like below.

```
Pattern.compile("http://(www\\.)?url-example\\.com(?!.*\\.br\\b).*");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bL8zT9/2)

`(?!.*\\.br)` negative lookahead asserts that the character following the `.com` would be any but not of `.br`

```
String s1 = "http://url-example.com";
String s2 = "http://url-example.com/anything";
String s3 = "http://www.url-example.com";
String s4 = "http://www.url-example.com/anything";
String s5 = "http://url-example.com.br";
String s6 = "http://www.url-example.com.br";
String s7 = "http://www.url-example.com.br/anything";
System.out.println(s1.matches("http://(www\\.)?url-example\\.com(?!.*\\.br\\b).*"));
System.out.println(s2.matches("http://(www\\.)?url-example\\.com(?!.*\\.br\\b).*"));
System.out.println(s3.matches("http://(www\\.)?url-example\\.com(?!.*\\.br\\b).*"));
System.out.println(s4.matches("http://(www\\.)?url-example\\.com(?!.*\\.br\\b).*"));
System.out.println(s5.matches("http://(www\\.)?url-example\\.com(?!.*\\.br\\b).*"));
System.out.println(s6.matches("http://(www\\.)?url-example\\.com(?!.*\\.br\\b).*"));
System.out.println(s7.matches("http://(www\\.)?url-example\\.com(?!.*\\.br\\b).*"));
```

**Output:**

```
true
true
true
true
false
false
false
```